# Underscore validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I used this code to validate underscore. But it does not work for underscore(keyCode =95). But work for other key codes. How to validate underscore ?? I want to avoid of typing underscore..

```
function ValidateUnderscore(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 95)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Where are you using this function? If I'm not wrong, this doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy isnot it because underscore is combination of keyboard buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/kNHe6/

The keycode for underscore (and minus) is 189.  So, change your check to do 189 instead of 95

Assuming you want the possibility to have minus though, consider something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/U32C9/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#text").keypress(function(e) {
        if(String.fromCharCode(e.which) == '_')
            e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: yes, this is the better solution than detecting alt code

Comment: Thanks Vizkos. It is working properly. But when I type underscore, little moment it shows and disappear. cant we fix that issue?

Comment: @Isuru - I have modified my answer to suit your request.